# Get textContent inside selected elements

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the output bellow from a document.querySelector.innerHTML then pushing inside an array.
I would like to filter only the numbers inside . Removing everything and just show me the numbers.

Code:

```
const games = await page.evaluate(() => {
                
return [].concat.apply([], document.querySelectorAll('#content-wrapper'))
               
.map((e) => {
const numbers = [];
for(let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
const bets = e.querySelector('#content-wrapper > div > div:nth-child(5) > iv:nth-child('+i+')').innerHTML;
numbers.push({ bets })
}
return {numbers}
})

});
```

Actual Output

```
{
numbers: '<h4 style="">List 100 </h4>\n' +
'<span>1</span>\n' +
'\n'
'<span>2</span>\n' +
'\n'
'<span class="ok">3</span>\n' +
'\n'
'<span class="ok">4</span>\n' +
'\n'
'<span>5</span>\n' +
'\n'
'<span class="ok">6</span>\n' +
\n'
'<span>7</span>\n' +
'\n'
'<span class="ok">8</span>\n' +
'\n'
'<span class="ok">9</span>\n' +
'\n'
'<span class="ok">10</span>\n' +
'\n'
}
```

Desired Output

```
{
List 100,
3,
4,
6,
8,
9,
10
}
```

Comment: did you try `textContent`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Comment: Hey @RameshReddy, textContent is returning empty. I'm trying to get the numbers inside the tags but I think I need to pass through all the childs(i).innerHTML first then do some filter to get the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method and `forEach` to store all `span` with class `ok` and `h4` - `textContent`

```js
//Get all elements with class ok
let children = document.querySelectorAll('.ok, h4')

//Store data
let store = []

//Foreach data
children.forEach(data => store.push(data.textContent.trim()))

//Console.log
console.log(store)
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <h4 style="">List 100 </h4>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span class="ok">3</span>
  <span class="ok">4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span class="ok">6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span class="ok">8</span>
  <span class="ok">9</span>
  <span class="ok">10</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You can remove `let getData = ` because `forEach` returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using **innerHTML**, you can loop through the children and get the text.

```js
function extractnumbers(){
  let children = document.getElementById('container').querySelectorAll('h4,.ok');
  let numbers = [...children].map((node)=> node.textContent.trim());
  console.log(numbers);
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <h4 style="">List 100 </h4>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span class="ok">3</span>
  <span class="ok">4</span>
  <span>5</span>
  <span class="ok">6</span>
  <span>7</span>
  <span class="ok">8</span>
  <span class="ok">9</span>
  <span class="ok">10</span>
</div>
<br><br>
<button onclick='extractnumbers()'> Extract Numbers</button>

<h4> The output is printed in console.</h4>
```

Comment: Running the extract numbers is showing all the numbers.

Comment: I see. But know I've already accepted the another answer. Thnx anyway!